# An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. Correct the classpath of your application

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, pom.xml

I have read the other questions similar to this one, but the answers did not help me. It is a project born in spring boot but it was imported in eclipse.

OUTPUT:

```
    An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:160)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.<init>(java.util.function.Supplier)'

The method's class, org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/segreteria/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.9/spring-expression-5.3.9.jar!/org/springframework/expression/spel/support/StandardTypeConverter.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter: file:/C:/Users/segreteria/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.9/spring-expression-5.3.9.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter
```

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.giuggiola</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parlamento</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bootjpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    
    
    
    
    
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <!--    <scope>runtime</scope> -->
         <version>2.6.3</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>

    
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <version>2.6.2</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
   
    </dependency>
    
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        
        
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-55</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency> 
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.52</version>
    </dependency>


     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson- 
    dataformat-xml 
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!--  
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-core -->
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.22</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <!--  <version>2.6.4</version>  -->
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter- 
    parent -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>




    </dependencies> 
    

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
        
        
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
   

    </build>

    </project>
```

Terminal:

```
    mvn dependency:tree
      ...


    [INFO] com.giuggiola:Parlamento:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
     [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data- 
    elasticsearch:jar:2.6.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
    logging:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.28:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:4.2.4:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty4-client:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.67.Final:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.67.Final:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.67.Final:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.67.Final:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.67.Final:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.67.Final:compile
    [INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.67.Final:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level- 
    client:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-secure-sm:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat- 
    smile:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat- 
    yaml:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat- 
    cbor:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-geo:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:8.8.0:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-cli:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.2:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.8.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.4:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.2:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:5.7.0-1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  \- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-plugin- 
    classloader:jar:7.12.1:runtime
    [INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest- 
    client:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.14:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.4:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.14:compile
    [INFO] |     |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:mapper-extras-client:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:parent-join-client:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:aggs-matrix-stats- 
    client:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:rank-eval-client:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:lang-mustache-client:jar:7.12.1:compile
    [INFO] |     |     \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.6:compile
    [INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.0.1-jre:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict- 
    with-guava:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.12.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.7.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.6.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.32.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.2.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.27.0-GA:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.22:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.2.3.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons- 
    annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype- 
    jdk8:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype- 
    jsr310:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter- 
    names:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.5.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.23:runtime
    [INFO] +- com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-55:jar:2.14.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb- 
    annotations:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.4:compile
    [INFO] |     \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-servlet-api:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jsp-api:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-el-api:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:jar:3.26.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper-el:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-api:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util-scan:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-util:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-resolver-provider:jar:3.8.6:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-impl:jar:1.6.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-api:jar:1.6.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-spi:jar:1.6.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.resolver:maven-resolver-util:jar:1.6.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.3.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.5:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:no_aop:4.2.2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.3.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.6.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.26:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:2.1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile
    [INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:jar:9.0.52:provided
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.52:compile
    [INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
    [INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.22:provided
    [INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok-maven:pom:1.18.20.0:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.5.4:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.5.4:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.4:test
    [INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.5.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.7:test
    [INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.7:test
    [INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
    [INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.19.0:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.7.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.7.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.7.2:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.2:test
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.7.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.9.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.22:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.9.0:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.9:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.9:test
    [INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.8.2:test
    [INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.4:compile
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

i excluded from the dependency tree, spring-expression.jar 5.3.9, but it gave me other errors, i tried to add new version of spring-context to the pom, but return to the initial error

Output:

```
    15:02:18.065 [Thread-0] DEBUG 
 
 



2022-09-06 15:02:19.487  INFO 5312 --- [  restartedMain] com.giuggiola.ParlamentoApplication      : Starting ParlamentoApplication using Java 18.0.2.1 on UTENTE-4KLNCD55 with PID 5312 (C:\Users\segreteria\eclipse-workspace\Parlamento2\target\classes started by segreteria in C:\Users\segreteria\eclipse-workspace\Parlamento2)
2022-09-06 15:02:19.489  INFO 5312 --- [  restartedMain] com.giuggiola.ParlamentoApplication      : The following profiles are active: @spring.profiles.active@
2022-09-06 15:02:19.815  INFO 5312 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-09-06 15:02:19.816  INFO 5312 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-09-06 15:02:20.000 ERROR 5312 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/expression/ParserContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:684) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at o



SOLUTION:

problem solved by putting the following dependencies in the pom


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- 
     https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring- 
    expression -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.22</version>
    </dependency>
```